# Should synchronized accessed methods be synchronized?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized, synchronized-block

I want to access a method from within an `synchronized` block. Here is an example:

```
public void doSomething() {
    // simple stuff

    // a block to reduce the synchronized code to
    // what really needs to be synchronized.
    synchronized(this) {
        if (precondition) {
            doSequentialStuff();
        }
    }
}

private void doSequentialStuff() {
    // do stuff needs to be performed sequentially.
}
```

To write clean code I wondered whether it would be good to make the method `doSequentialStuff` explicitly `synchronized`. IMHO this would make no difference in semantic since the lock is in both cases `this` and the method is guaranteed to be accessed only from the `synchronized` block. I hope to increase the readability.

Any advice?

**Edit:**
I modified the example to incorporate the comments.

Comment: Also you ensure that you do not forget the `synchronized` block if you latter use the method from another code in your class. I would clearly put it in the method.

Comment: Side note: synchronized and "heavy stuff" often don't go well together...

Comment: @Mat: You'r right: Its a classical check-than-act problem. I changed the example.

Comment: @assylias: indeed, the productive code dose something sequentially and not heavy. But can you explain - in short - why synchronized and "heavy stuff" often don't go well together?

Comment: @scheffield the synchronized block is executed sequentially - if what you do inside takes time, this can quickly become a bottleneck where threads will spend a lot of time waiting for the monitor. In general, you want to keep synchronized section as small as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no legitimate code path by which `doHeavyStuff` may be executed without holding the lock, then **by all means** make it `synchronized` in order to preempt any future bugs introduced by an unwary developer. The readability of code can only improve what way.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to go with an assert to check that the lock is being held. Note, you do need assertions enabled for the check to be performed.

```
assert Thread.holdsLock(this);
```

Generally if you are using this sort of private method it tends to indicate that you should split the class into two. An outer layer does the locking and perhaps other things appropriate for the client, whereas a deeper layer is more concerned with implementation.

Use of `this` to lock is dubious. Generally it's better to use a private explicit lock object.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://weblogs.java.net/blog/mason/archive/2006/09/rechecking_doub.html, it has got similar pattern covered (uses singleton as an example, but you can easily retrofit it for your case).

Comment: No, the link is specifically about double-checked locking.

Comment: Correct, but the abstract class in the article has got method  `invalid(X value)` which is similar case to OP and easy to retrofit. I have clarified my answer though.

Comment: Main point: if *precondition* doesn't depend on the state that is protected by the lock (and mutated by `doHeavyStuff`), then the double-checked idiom is superfluous.